# Divs next to each but one appearing off the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want 2 divs appearing next to each other but one to appear off the page so that when I perform my transition, they both shunt to left and the second div rolls onto screen replacing the first div. currently at the moment all I can do is get the div to appear underneath one, here is my code.

```
div class="all-items" >
    <div class="first" >
    </div>
    <div class="second">
    </div>
  </div>

.all-items div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.first {
  width: 100%;
}

.second{
  width: 100%;
}
```

I then add classes for my translations which work however the divs appear on the page and on top of each other whereas I want the div .second to appear off the page to begin with and come on when I click my button

Comment: you should apply `white-space` property: set it to `nowrap` for the parent and `normal` for the innermost `div`s

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've set the display for the child elements to inline-block. This wraps elements when they are too wide for the container, so it's not going to get you the solution you're looking for.

One way to get what you want is with position: absolute and left/right: Xvw. [Example bin](http://jsbin.com/gulaqurubu/edit?html,css,js,output).

```
.all-items {
  position: relative;
}

.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0vw;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.second{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100vw;
  transition: left 1s;
}
```

What you're doing here is:

- Set the parent container to position: relative
- Set children to position: absolute, top: 0
- The first div will have left: 0
- The second div will start with left: 100vw and when you toggle will transition to left: 0vw.

The two children with position: absolute allows you to lay one div over the other. By toggling the `left` property you can transition them to slide on and off the screen. By using `vw` as your `left` unit, you know that the div will always be fully off the page.

Comment: that seemed to position them on top of each other for me

Comment: @TheWalrus That's what you want, I thought. That last `left: 50vw` I set so that you could see them overlap. Change it to `left: 100vw` and you'll see it is completely off the screen. Change it to `left: 0` and you'll see they completely overlap. When you add your transition that change will animate the blue to slide over the red. Is that not what you wanted? To get the red to slide off too, set `left: -100vw`

Comment: @TheWalrus I've added transitions and updated the JSBin. If you go to that bin and type in different `left` values, you'll see the divs transitioning.